# How to remove notification popups for banshee?

Tags: banshee, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable notifications on track change?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33946/disable-notifications-on-track-change)

I can't stand it when Banshee tells me a new song is playing. I know what I'm playing, so I don't need it to tell me. :)

How can I disable the notification popups?