# How do I stop Banshee from putting a notification in the panel for every song?

Tags: 11.10, banshee, gnome-classic

As a playlist or internet radio station plays, a notification pops up in the top right corner every time the song changes.

I can't find any way either within Banshee or settings in general to stop this.

How do I stop Banshee from putting a notification in the panel for every song?

Further, can I stop Banshee from outputting any notifications at all?

***Update:*** I tried going into Banshee → Edit → Preferences → Extensions, and disabled the Sound Menu Integration, but this does not seem to stop notifications.

Comment: Does this Q&A resolve this? if so, this is a dupe... http://askubuntu.com/questions/33946/disable-notifications-on-track-change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to *Edit → Preferences → Extensions*, then disable the *Sound Menu Integration* (make sure that also the "Notification Area Icon" plugin is disabled).

Comment: Is there no way to disable notifications separately from the Sound Menu Integration?

Comment: Update: Tried this and it unfortunately does not seem to stop notifications.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried this in a 11.10 virtual machine: if you have both plugins disabled, there are no notifcations. Plus, it seems the sound indicator integration is **not** influenced by this setting!

Comment: Okay, this works now that the "Notification Area Icon" plugin is also disabled. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In Natty, Banshee won't show up in the notification area, so I ran the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'banshee']"
```

This adds Banshee to a "whitelist" of applications allowed to be shown in the notification area.

Logged out, and logged back in again. Then in Banshee, went to Edit -> Preferences -> Extensions. Disabled `Sound Menu Integration` and enabled `Notification Area Icon`. Then, right clicked the notification icon and disabled show notifications.

I then disabled `Notification Area Icon extension`, and tried `re-enabling Sound Menu` Integration. This, however, still showed notifications whenever the track was changed. I found out though, that you don't need the `Sound Menu Integration` plug in enabled for Banshee to work in the sound menu

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33946/disable-notifications-on-track-change)